# Cypher - multiple relationships with same label, i want to delete just one

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following schema:
(Node a and b are identified by id and are the same in both relationships)

```
(a)-[r:RelType {comment:'a comment'} ]-(b)
(a)-[r:RelType {comment:'another comment'} ]-(b)
```

So i have 2 nodes, and an arbitrary number of relationships between them. I want to delete just one of the relationships, and i don t care which one. How can i do this?

I have tried this, but it does not work:

```
match (a {id:'aaa'})-[r:RelType]-(b {id:'bbb'}) where count(r)=1 delete r;
```

Any ideas?

Here is the real-world query:

```
match (order:Order {id:'order1'}),(produs:Product {id:'supa'}),
(order)-[r:ordprod {status:'altered'}]->(produs) with r limit 1 set r.status='alteredAgain'
return (r);
```

The problem is Chypher says
    Set 1 property, returned 1 row in 219 ms
, but when i inspect the database, it turns out all relationships have been updated.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following:

```
match (a {id:'aaa'})-[r:RelType]-(b {id:'bbb'}) 
with r
limit 1
delete r
```

Comment: @MihaiRaulea, here is console: http://console.neo4j.org/r/72mf5n I changed the query to update a counter on the relationship rather then change text or delete. Could you alter the console to replicate your problem, generate a new link and post it back here?

Comment: @MihaiRaulea Did you actually try the query Stefan gave you? the one you edited into your answer is different, with a broken up match pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps(As per my understanding you are trying to modify a relationship between two given nodes)

```
MATCH (order:Order {id:'order1'})-[r:ordprod {status:'altered'}]->(produs:Product {id:'supa'})
WITH order,r,produs 
LIMIT 1 
DELETE r
WITH order,produs
CREATE (order:Order {id:'order1'})-[r:ordprod {status:'alteredAgain'}]->(produs:Product {id:'supa'})
return (r);
```

And the reason for all your relationships getting updated is that after your `WITH` clause you are passing only r ie the relationship which may be same between all such nodes of label `Order` and `Product`. So when you do `r.status = 'alteredagain'` it changes all the relationships instead of changing between those two specific nodes that you matched in the beginning of your cypher query. Pass them too in the `WITH` and it will work fine!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement data structure like your's (Mihai's). and gone with both solutions; i.e., Stefan's and Sumit's. Stefan's solution is working at my side. Mihai, are you still facing any problems?